# Math.random generates same number

Tags: java

I am a beginner so please bear with me. I created a for loop to create a random number in between 0 and 9. But it keeps generating 0.  How do I fix this?

```
int x = (int)(Math.random()*10);![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBPsb.jpg)
```

My program is to randomly generate any  amount of numbers(from user input) from 0-9 and the program tells how many of each number there are. Sorry if the pic isnt good enough. My problem it keeps giving me 0 for the numbers generated.

Comment: Post your attempt. **How** are you generating your random number?

Comment: Int x = (int)Math.random()*10.

Comment: Post your code in oyour question. Show the for loop and the math code. Do not add it as a comment.

Comment: `int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast only after multiplying, otherwise the result of `random()` is floored to 0:

```
int x = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
```

Comment: That is the same code that I used

Comment: @Tyler No it's not. Look carefully.

Comment: @Tyler Exactly. The parentheses tells the compiler to calculate `Math.random() * 10` before casting the result to `int`.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you very much